# Cannot figure out efficient SQL for 3-table INNER JOIN (MySQL) - "customers also bought" functionality

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add the typical "customers who bought 'x' also bought 'y'" functionality to my website. Here is the table structure:

```
Table: qb_invoice
+--------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                          | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| qbsql_id                       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| TxnID                          | varchar(40)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| Customer_ListID                | varchar(40)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| Customer_FullName              | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

Table: qb_invoice_invoiceline
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| qbsql_id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| Invoice_TxnID           | varchar(40)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| Item_ListID             | varchar(40)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| Item_FullName           | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

Table: qb_customer
+-------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                               | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| qbsql_id                            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ListID                              | varchar(40)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| Name                                | varchar(41)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
+-------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Given an **Item_ListID** I'd like a fast, efficient query to return a list of **Item_ListID**'s along with a COUNT of the number of customers that ordered each item in the list, where all customers have in common the initially supplied **Item_ListID**.

Right now I have the following SQL that works, but is very slow:

```
SELECT qb_invoice_invoiceline.Item_FullName, count(*) as 'nummy'
FROM qb_invoice_invoiceline
WHERE qb_invoice_invoiceline.Invoice_TxnID = 
ANY (SELECT qb_invoice.TxnID
FROM qb_invoice 
INNER JOIN qb_customer ON qb_invoice.Customer_ListID = qb_customer.ListID
INNER JOIN qb_invoice_invoiceline ON qb_invoice.TxnID = qb_invoice_invoiceline.Invoice_TxnID
WHERE qb_invoice_invoiceline.Item_ListID = '1360000-57')
GROUP BY qb_invoice_invoiceline.Item_ListID
ORDER BY nummy DESC
```

I appreciate your help!

Here is the 'explain' output:

```
+----+--------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                  | type  | possible_keys             | key         | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | qb_invoice_invoiceline | index | NULL                      | Item_ListID | 123     | NULL                                    | 19690 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | qb_invoice_invoiceline | ref   | Invoice_TxnID,Item_ListID | Item_ListID | 123     | const                                   |     8 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | qb_invoice             | ref   | Customer_ListID,TxnID     | TxnID       | 123     | func                                    |   206 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | qb_customer            | ref   | ListID                    | ListID      | 123     | devdb.qb_invoice.Customer_ListID |    18 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+--------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can use 'explain [query]' to analyze how the query will be performed by the DB on MySQL. Also,it's very helpful to add the result of 'explain' to the question.

Comment: The count in your query is making it run slow. If you do a count(*) with joins in your query it counts all the columns (from multiple tables) in every possible join.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tried changing the COUNT function to use a specific column and it did not seem to have an effect on speed.

Comment: I've added the 'explain' output (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Your query may be slow if there are no indexes available on the varchar fields that you are joining on. Can you give details on the indexes that are present on these tables?

I think that the query would benefit from indexes on qb_invoice.TxnID and qb_customer.ListID, and on qb_invoice_invoiceline.Item_ListID.

Comment: All of the fields that you suggest are already indexes... any other ideas?